# ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'float' when using pandas.read_csv()

Tags: python, pandas

I found what was generating this strange behaviour: in one of the modules I had introduced an error `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.0d}'.format` that only manifested when I print the DataFrame. I'll leave here my original question, so it may help others.

I'm pursuing a bug in my code, and right now I find that in a part of the code (a module) I can read a *csv* into a pandas DataFrame with no issues (e.g. in the end I can do `df` in the debug console), and on the other part (another module) I can read a *csv* into a pandas Dataframe, but when I try to print it I get the following error: `ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'float'` (when I do `df` in the debug console I get `<pandas.core.frame.DataFrame object at 0x172dcad60>`).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 995, in __repr__
    self.to_string(
  File "/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1131, in to_string
    return fmt.DataFrameRenderer(formatter).to_string(
  File "/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 1053, in to_string
    string = string_formatter.to_string()
  File "/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/string.py", line 25, in to_string
    text = self._get_string_representation()
  File "/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/string.py", line 40, in _get_string_representation
    strcols = self._get_strcols()
  File "/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/string.py", line 31, in _get_strcols
    strcols = self.fmt.get_strcols()
  File "/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 540, in get_strcols
    strcols = self._get_strcols_without_index()
  File "/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 804, in _get_strcols_without_index
    fmt_values = self.format_col(i)
  File "/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 818, in format_col
    return format_array(
  File "/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 1240, in format_array
    return fmt_obj.get_result()
  File "/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 1271, in get_result
    fmt_values = self._format_strings()
  File "/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 1518, in _format_strings
    return list(self.get_result_as_array())
  File "/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 1435, in get_result_as_array
    return format_with_na_rep(self.values, self.formatter, self.na_rep)
  File "/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 1427, in format_with_na_rep
    [
  File "/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 1428, in <listcomp>
    formatter(val) if not m else na_rep
ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'float'
```

The precise instruction to read is equal on both modules(!), but I'm getting

```
df = pd.read_csv(results_path / f'{results}.csv')
```

I can't reproduce this, unless I run it through the existing code (through the existing modules). If I use a new program that simply reads the csv with the `pd.read_csv()` function the problem does not happen.
I can't really make sense of this, so I'm leaving this here hoping that someone figures what I may be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is with your data: it seems to exist both int and float values. You should try to convert the column to float type. (it's a parameter from read_csv method)

Here are some people with a similar problem:

- [String formatting with "{0:d}".format gives Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'float'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627605/string-formatting-with-0d-format-gives-unknown-format-code-d-for-object-o)
- [String Formatting (ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'str')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69179799/string-formatting-valueerror-unknown-format-code-d-for-object-of-type-str)
- [Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'unicode'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924879/unknown-format-code-f-for-object-of-type-unicode)

Comment: Thanks but I've checked those and this is a different issue.